# Watch TV without using Media Center

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, windows-media-center, tv, dell-studio

I have a DELL Studio XPS 1640 with an inbuilt TV Tuner.

The only problem is I have to use Windows Media Center to watch TV. Is it possible to set up VLC Player or some other player that can allow me to watch TV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Media portal is free with many features

http://www.team-mediaportal.com/

also take a look at

http://www.videohelp.com/